# How can i call value which is store in variable from one function to another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, function

I want to call **fb_name** variable from this function to another function so i can get facebook name in another function. Anyone can help me how can i call this variable?

I'm trying to call this function in another function like this  facebook_login() but it always shows popup in another function because i'm using signInWithPopup method.

```
    let facebook_login = () => {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
        var user = result.user;
        var fb_name = user.displayName;
        console.log("this user ==>", fb_name);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    });

    var hide = document.getElementById("hide");
    hide.removeAttribute("id", "hide");
    
    var login_screen = document.getElementById("login-screen");
    login_screen.setAttribute("id", "hide");


}
```

Comment: Impossible in JS only some workaround possible - set global var inside, sent object to the function and set its property, etc.